# SQL - Actualización múltiples filas

Tags: sql, sql-server, update, sql-server-2019

Necesito actualizar cada fila (ARTAL) from  'ART' table. Quiero que cada fila artal coja el nombre desde una selección que he hecho en (DART).

Gracias

```
UPDATE ART
  SET ARTAL (SELECT SUBSTRING(DART,1,3) + '' + SUBSTRING(DART,5,2) + '' + SUBSTRING(DART,9,2)FROM ART WHERE...ETC
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. La pregunta en español. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Despúes de `SET ARTAL` tiene que ir un igual. Además la select que está entre paréntesis tiene que devolver obligatoriamente un solo valor). Si necesitas una respuestas mejor, deberás de concretar el escenario que tienes.

Comment: Hola, Gracias por responder lo primero.  Es un listado de artículos y necesito que la actualización se aplique a cada código de artículo, pero claro, con la subquery solo devuelve un valor, no se si es posible actualizar todas las filas.

Comment: Deberías de exponer claramente lo que tienes y lo que esperas, y seguro que encontramos una solución fácil. Ya que existen muchas posibilidades. Pero pon lo que tienes, no en texto, sino con datos, y lo que esperas.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Qué es DART? Esos puntos suspensivos en el WHERE qué representan? Qué datos de prueba puedes mostrarnos de la tabla ART? Cuál es el resultado esperado en esos datos de prueba? :)

Answer (score 0):

he tratado de colaborar con lo que entendí de tu consulta, pero lo que te han comentado es válido y facilita muchísimo las rtas.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ART
create table #ART (ARTAL varchar (255) , id_art int)
insert into #ART ( id_art) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DART
create table #DART (DART varchar (13) , id_dart int)
insert into #DART (DART, id_Dart) 
values   ('1123456789QWE',1),('2123456789ASD',2)
        ,('3123456789ZXC',3),('4123456789RTY',4)
        ,('5123456789UIO',5),('6123456789FGH',6)
        ,('7123456789JKL',7),('8123456789VBN',8)
        ,('9123456789MLP',9);
        

select * from #DART 


UPDATE a
SET ARTAL = SUBSTRING(DART,1,3) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(DART,5,2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(DART,9,2) 
FROM #ART a
INNER JOIN #DART B
ON A.id_art = B.id_dart


select * from #ART
```